# How to mirror Google Glass screen to PC/Mac?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I wanted to share my experience on how to mirror Google Glass screen on PC or Mac so that you can share it during your presentations, etc. Please see my answer below or add your answers.

Comment: [Self-answering](/help/self-answer) requires you to post an actual question and an actual answer. A question that isn't a question will be closed as unclear, regardless of any self-answering

Answer (score 6):

1)

- Download DroidScreen jar file from here:
  http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com
- You need to have Android SDK/Java installed
- Connect Glass to your PC (Glass should be set to Debug mode), use the following command or double click on the .jar file to run it:
  java -jar droidAtScreen-1.0.1.jar
- On the first run, java program asks for the full path of adb program which is in the platform-tools directory.

2)

- Download the ASM.jar file from Android Screen Monitor (ASM) (as of November 2013):
  https://code.google.com/p/android-screen-monitor/
- You need to have Android SDK/Java installed and have the tools and platform-tools directories in your PATH. You can do so as follows:

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/AndroidSDKDirectory/tools/

Comment: I just installed the ASM myself on Mac - double clicking the jar file in Finder keep giving me an error "Could not find adb, please install Android SDK and set path to adb", despite that my PATH was set correctly.  Launching the jar file from terminal worked though, just in case someone else is scratching their head on this same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a video detailing how to mirror your glass to your screen via usb cable.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGsfpV9FdBs&feature=youtu.be&noredirect=1

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps on this [link](http://dmzilla.com/2014/07/21/how-to-display-or-mirror-an-android-device-screen-on-pc-no-root/) and download Android Screen Monitor.

use command line to open ASM

```
java -jar \[DMZilla\]-Android-Screen-Monitor-\(ASM\).jar
```